# tableview compressed, label off center and can't see button

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, uitableview, adaptive-layout

I'm done with the backend part of my app but am STUCK on the front-end. I'm not sure what's going on but the tableview is compressed, the label is off center and the button has completely disappeared. I'm not making the cells individually; I only made one and then using code to recreate the rest of the cells. I made one cell on the storyboard. I've also tried working with constraints. How can I fix my tableview so it has an adaptive layout? [image]

Comment: Show the code and image of your interfacebuilder where you created cell, guess you' re setup layout incorrectly.

Comment: I figured it out. I'm still not sure on how to set constraints so I just used "reset to suggested constraints" for everything and everything fell into place. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Use size Class to define your design over storyboard.

it makes you comfortable to design with adaptive layouts.

Comment: You mean check the "Use size classes" option? I did that but I can't set the constraints for the cells and nothing else is working.